# C. S. Lewis' description of heaven and hell contrasted with Catholicism

Tags: catholicism, afterlife, cs-lewis, cs-lewis-theology

I was going through *The Great Divorce* by C S Lewis and was wondering how much in line with Scripture his descriptions of heaven and hell are. I've heard very different descriptions coming from saints like St. Teresa of Jesus and they seem to conflict in many ways.

Lewis describes hell as the person's choice to reject God and to stay in hell (the gates of hell are locked from the inside), whereas others describe it as God placing the damned there and locking them up. There's also a conflict in the "design" of hell. Lewis and others describe it as a torture of the mind, whereas others describe it as a physical torture.

There seems to be support for Lewis' view in the Bible, such as the parable of the rich man and Lazarus where the rich man doesn't want to go to where Lazarus is but rather wants Lazarus to come to him. But also there's support for the other views because it's written that one can be cast into hell.

How does C.S. Lewis's descriptions of heaven and hell compare with the teaching of the Catholic Church?

Comment: Christians have lots of different opinions about what sort of heaven/hell the Bible describes, so you'd need to pick one particular denomination if you want to ask this sort of question here.

Comment: How about now? Or is it still to broad?

Comment: C.S. Lewis was an Anglican, I believe. I think the problem here is that you are only likely to get opinion-based answers, even if you have asked for on Catholic answers.

Comment: I understand. Is the question not worth asking then?

Comment: @curiousdannii This is actually a good Q to use my proposed tag `cs-lewis-theology` (see [meta answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7051/10672)) if you think we can rephrase the question as a compare/contrast between CS Lewis view of heaven & hell (which can be established objectively) with Catholicism (which can also be established objectively).  The sections of the answer would be 1) what truths are common to both, 2) what C.S. Lewis adds (as pious speculation, not doctrinal description), 3) where the speculation borderline contradicts Catholic doctrine.

Comment: @Suryetto *The Great Divorce* happens to be one of the most significant books for me.  *The Last Battle* final chapters also present C.S. Lewis's same views on heaven and hell but in a different genre.  Both I tag as *pious speculation* which fill in the gap **not** provided by the Bible **nor** by mainline church traditions.  It's not surprising then to find his speculations contradict certain descriptions by the saints or by certain medieval poets although I believe all of them affirm the same revealed truths.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Contrasting CS Lewis' personal theology with other groups is fine, but I don't think we should call the common 'Mere Christianity' theology cs-lewis-theology. In any case it's not needed here.